# foreach loop with user-friends on facebook app

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using php trying to make a sample site where all the user's friends (who are also on the site) are displayed (their name and their id). I can get the friends via a request which gets put in an object. But I don't have any idea where to go from there.

This is what I want:

```
foreach ($friends as $friend) {
   echo $friend['name'];
   echo $friend['username'];
}
```

Obviously this is not at all the syntax you have to have to do this since it's an object and not an array, and there's a paging url in there since it only returns 5 friends at a time.

Is there anywhere online which tells how to do this? I can't find anything like it. Or does anyone here know how to do it and willing to give an example of how to do it? I'm sure I'm not the only one out there needing this information.

FYI when I do a var_dump on the graph object I get this:

> object(Facebook\GraphObject)#16 (1) { ["backingData":protected]=>
>   array(3) { ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
>   ["name"]=> string(9) "Amy Grant" ["id"]=> string(17) "101534.....264"
>   } } ["paging"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["next"]=> string(411)
>   "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/87...0837/friends..." } ["summary"]=>
>   object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["total_count"]=> int(386) } } }

Comment: You should use one of method which returns you array from this `GraphObject`. It could be `$obj->asArray()` or `$obj->getProprtyAsArray()`. Unfortunately I'm unable to test it right now. Look at documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is what seems to work. I'm not sure about the paging part of it as I don't have more than 5 facebook friends currently registered with my test app (obviously). Does anyone know if the asArray() puts all the friends into the array? Or does it only put 5 (because of the paging)?

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/friends'
);
$response = $request->execute();

$obj = $response->getGraphObject();
$_SESSION['fb']['friends'] = $obj->asArray();
$friends = $_SESSION['fb']['friends']['data'];
foreach ($friends as $friend) {
    echo $friend->name;
    echo $friend->id;
}
```